# Pagination in second table

Tags: laravel-livewire

**how can i page the second table? Or is this shape incorrect?**

1. Here is my render function.

   ```
   public function render()
   {


     $data = DB::table('view_log_acesso_telas')


            ->join('contact_std_parceiros_usuarios','view_log_acesso_telas.id_usuario','=','contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.id_usuario')
               ->select(
                   'contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.id_usuario',
                   'contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.nome',
                   'view_log_acesso_telas.data_inicio'
               )
               ->groupBy(
                   'contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.id_usuario',
                   'contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.nome',
                   'view_log_acesso_telas.data_inicio'
               )
               ->having('nome', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
               ->orderBy('view_log_acesso_telas.data_inicio','desc')
               ->orderBy('contact_std_parceiros_usuarios.nome','desc')
               ->paginate($this->perPage);

   return view('livewire.relatorios.acessos.acessos-component',[
        'data' => $data,
   ]);
   ```

   }

```
    public function detail($id_usuario,$data_inicio)
    {
    $this->showDetails = true;
    $this->details = Acessos::where('id_usuario',$id_usuario)->where('data_inicio',$data_inicio)->paginate(10);
    }
```

[image: Error log]

Please tell me how can I solve this?